# Пытаюсь установить и запустить formation-studio

Tags: python, консоль, конструктор

Пытаюсь сделать это по гайду на гитхабе.
[1]: https://github.com/ObaraEmmanuel/Formation

```
    C:\Users\strel>pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/obaraemmanuel/Formation@master
Collecting git+https://github.com/obaraemmanuel/Formation@master
  Cloning https://github.com/obaraemmanuel/Formation (to revision master) to c:\users\strel\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-z8mhycbh
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/obaraemmanuel/Formation 'C:\Users\strel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-z8mhycbh'
  Resolved https://github.com/obaraemmanuel/Formation to commit a7a63499aef37973f290f7685fc14a6f1b7561ed
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs in c:\users\strel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from formation-studio==0.6.2) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-tkdnd>=0.2.1 in c:\users\strel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from formation-studio==0.6.2) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\strel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from formation-studio==0.6.2) (10.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ttkwidgets>=0.12.0 in c:\users\strel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from python-tkdnd>=0.2.1->formation-studio==0.6.2) (0.13.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 23.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\strel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\strel>formation-studio
"formation-studio" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\strel>pip install formation-studio
Requirement already satisfied: formation-studio in c:\users\strel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-tkdnd>=0.2.1 in c:\users\strel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from formation-studio) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\strel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from formation-studio) (10.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs in c:\users\strel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from formation-studio) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ttkwidgets>=0.12.0 in c:\users\strel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from python-tkdnd>=0.2.1->formation-studio) (0.13.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 23.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\strel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\strel>formation-studio
"formation-studio" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Я совсем в установке штук для питона не шарю, помогите пж(